# Custom type parameters for KFP components

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

I'm working with KFP components and I want to pass a custom type parameters, it threw this error `TypeError: Artifacts must have both a schema_title and a schema_version, separated by` @`. Got: SentenceTransformer`. I read from this https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/data-types/parameters/ and it says that the component can only accept python built-in type. Any idea how can I pass custom type parameters?

Thanks

Comment: How would you pass a custom type parameter in the first place? Via API call? Do you really need to pass the object or would the name of the class suffice so you can create an instance in your Kfp component?

Comment: Please share if https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/8827 solved your problem OR you found some different solution?